# platform.win32_ver() reporting wrong windows version

Tags: python, windows, version, windows-10

My computer is on Windows 10 and my program can only work with Windows 10. Naturally, I've used `platform.win32_ver()` to get the build number so my program can check. However, this function is returning the following:

```
('8', '6.2.9200', '', 'Multiprocessor Free')
```

when it should be returning:

```
('10', '10.0.10240', '', 'Multiprocessor Free')
```

What could be causing this?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe the Python version is older, not returning windows 10 yet.  Try importing this file:
http://bugs.python.org/file38102/win32_ver.py